# i got this error when i print some data from json : List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: json, flutter, dart

This is my code

```
 getMarker() async {
 List list = List();
String myUrl = serverUrl + "/markers";
var response = await http.get(myUrl,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',

    });
list = (json.decode(response.body) as List).
     map((data) => new Markers.fromJson(data)).toList();
     print(Markers.fromJson(list[0]['log']));
```

}

when i print the results i got this error 
'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map'

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18979

Comment: What is your Json and how does Markers look like?

Comment: Maybe log is a list?

Comment: [
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "lag": "32.222754",
            "log": "-7.939147"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "lag": "31.621737",
            "log": "-8.004948"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "lag": "31.636198",
            "log": "-8.017168"
        }
    ]
]

Answer (score 0):

It is only a parsing problem, the thing is that you have a list within another List, try the next:

`var list = json.decode(response.body)
    .map((data) => List<Marker>.from(data.map((x) => Marker.fromJson(x))))
    .toList(); 
    print(mList[0][0].log);`

also you can use [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io) to easily build your models and avoid to use the dynamic way.

Comment: now i have this error :  type '(dynamic) => List<Markers>' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Comment: Can you check your **Marker** class? I used this [MarkerClass](https://app.quicktype.io?share=WsQNDxebD3t7F1TVuxui) and the next fromJson method:                                                                                          `factory Marker.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Marker(
        id: json["id"],
        lag: json["lag"],
        log: json["log"],
    );`